# Usar subprocess para utilizar ordenes complejas de ffmpeg con pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, video

Utilizando pyQt quiero ejecutar ffmpeg. Con ordenes sencillas no hay problema. Por ejemplo:

```
def b3_clicked():
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', fileinput, fileoutput + '.mov'])
```

Esto funciona bien.
El problema es cuando quiero usar algo complejo.
Tras mucho tiempo conseguí que una serie de argumentos en ffmpeg pudiesen pegar fotogramas en negro delante y detrás de un vídeo:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1 -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=0:c=stereo:d=1" -i input.mov -filter_complex "[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; [blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v qtrle -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -timecode 00:02:00:00 output.mov
```

Esto funciona desde el terminal perfectamente.
La cuestión es que no se como pasarlo a pyQt. Cuando lo intento haciendo esto:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1', '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', "aevalsrc=0:c=stereo:d=1", '-i', fileinput, '-filter_complex', "[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; [blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" '-map', "[v]", '-map', "[a]", '-c:v', 'qtrle', '-c:a', 'pcm_s24le', '-ar', '48000', '-timecode', '00:02:00:00', filesaved])
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x56281d60f6c0] Unable to parse graph description
>   substring: "-map" Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument

Comment: Podrías hacer un script que encapsule la llamada. Asi solo pasas un solo argumento a `subprocess`... no tengo un ejemplo a la mano, pero recuerdo que era un script muy simple en sh. Una vez hice uno...

Comment: Gracias. Al no tener mucha experiencia, el script me parece más difícil. Ahora el método de @FJSevilla con shlex parece que puede funcionar pero tengo problemas con los comandos de ffmpeg, algo no va

Comment: Si la te sirve la respuesta de FJSevilla, por favor, márcala como aceptada. Debajo del marcador de votos, esta la marca/check/paloma para indicar que la respuesta te sirvió. Si tienes errores con `ffmpeg` realiza todas las preguntas que necesites. Recuerda incluir el error y un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias guardar tu comando en una cadena y usar `str.format` para agregar las variables, queda más reutilizable y legible que pasar 100 argumentos a `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess

fileinput = 'input.mov'
filesaved = 'output.mov'

comando = '\
ffmpeg \
-f lavfi \
-i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1 \
-f lavfi \
-i "aevalsrc=0:c=stereo:d=1" \
-i {} -filter_complex \
"[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; \
[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; \
[1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; \
[1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; \
[blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" \
-map "[a]" \
-c:v qtrle \
-c:a pcm_s24le \
-ar 48000 \
-timecode 00:02:00:00 {}'

subprocess.call(comando.format(fileinput, filesaved))
```

La cadena `comando` esta dividida en varias líneas usando la secuencia de escape `\` para que quede el script más legible. Es exactamente lo mismo que:

```
comando = 'ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1 -f lavfi -i "aevalsrc=0:c=stereo:d=1" -i {} -filter_complex "[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; [blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v qtrle -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -timecode 00:02:00:00 {}'
```

[`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) funciona mediante "campos de reemplazo" que se denotan con llaves {}. Cualquier cosa que no esté contenida en llaves se considera texto literal, que se copia sin cambios en la salida. Puedes usar el número que quieras de reemplazos en una misma cadena. Puedes pasarle cadenas o variables (incluidos enteros, floats...), operaciones, llamadas a funciones, etc:

```
c = 'mi cumpleaños'
cadena = 'La fecha de {} es el {} de {}.'.format(c, 20+1, 'Enero')
print(cadena)
```

Salida:

> La fecha de mi cumpleaños es el 21 de Enero.

**EDICIÓN:**

El método anterior funciona en Windows pero no en POSIX dado que si el argumento `args` de `subprocess.call` es una cadena, como en este caso, el manejo difiere. Se puede ver la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) para más información.

Puedes usar `shlex` para asegurar la correcta tokenización de `args`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex



fileinput = 'input.mov'
filesaved = 'output.mov'

comando = '\
ffmpeg \
-f lavfi \
-i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=1 \
-f lavfi \
-i "aevalsrc=0:c=stereo:d=1" \
-i {} -filter_complex \
"[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; \
[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; \
[1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; \
[1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; \
[blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" \
-map "[a]" \
-c:v qtrle \
-c:a pcm_s24le \
-ar 48000 \
-timecode 00:02:00:00 {}'

subprocess.call(shlex.split(comando.format(fileinput, filesaved)))
```

El código anterior lo he testeado tanto en Kubuntu 16.04 como en Windows con un vídeo propio y funciona en ambos sin problemas.

**P.D:** el error original en realidad era muy simple aunque cuesta encontrarlo. Se trata de un error a la hora de tokenizar los argumentos, **simplemente te falta una coma** en:

```
... [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" '-map',
                                        ^
                                        ^
                                        ^
```

La llamada debería ser:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=25:d=1', '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'aevalsrc=0:c=stereo:d=1', '-i', 'video.mkv', '-filter_complex', '[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; [blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]', '-map', '[v]', '-map', '[a]', '-c:v', 'qtrle', '-c:a', 'pcm_s24le', '-ar', '48000', '-timecode', '00:02:00:00', 'output.mov'])
```

Para evitarte estos problemas con llamadas que tengan muchos argumentos usa `shlex` como vimos antes o create script sh y llamalos con subprocess como recomienda toledano en su comentario.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación!! De todas formas acabo de aplicar lo que me indicas y me da error: _
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=25:d=1 -f lavfi -i ...."_

Comment: @salvaestudio ¿Bajo que sistema operativo trabajas?, es importante saberlo porque el comportamiento de subprocess difiere.

Comment: Estoy con Antergos en un Mac

Comment: La anterior llamada a ffmpeg si funcionaba: `subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', fileinput, fileoutput + '.mov'])` pero algo tiene esta nueva forma de llamar a ffmpeg que no me funciona ni siquiera con una variable comando más simple: subprocess.call(comando.format(fileinput, fileoutput))

Comment: Vale, culpa mia por presuponer cosas.... En  POSIX no se procesan de la misma forma que en Windows cuando args es una cadena. Voy a editar la pregunta a ver si te funciona.

Comment: @salvaestudio mira a ver si te funciona con lo añadido en la edición. Saludos.

Comment: Pues no me funciona. Creo que tu parte está bien porque arranca ffmpeg. Creo que es un problema de mi ffmpeg. Algo va mal porque he probado a ejecutarlo sin el programa en el terminal y también da el mismo error: `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=3 [blackstart]; [0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=5 [blackend]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.12 [audiostart]; [1:a] atrim=duration=0.2 [audioend]; [blackstart] [audiostart] [2:v] [2:a] [blackend] [audioend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58678/discussion-between-salvaestudio-and-fjsevilla).